# How to extract an adjacency matrix from OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, c++, graph

I would like to use graph algorithms from the Boost graph library on OSM data. What are my choices to use Openstreetmaps data from within a C++ program ? I need at least a flat file with a list of nodes and edges to build the graph using Boost graph. I am not looking for code that computes anything from the data. I'm thinking of something like an XML parser in C++ that I could integrate to my code.